# Unity Dependency Injection (constructor or property)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've been using Unity for some time in my project. I have a singleton Container which I use to register types and/or instances, and later resolve.

today i wanted to automate some of the instantiation by using property or constructor injection.

I started with Logger class. In Application start i have this code:

```
RegisterType<Logger, Logger>();
```

than in my ViewModel

```
[Dependency]
    public Logger MyLogger {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

here is how i instantiate the viewmodel that has this property (in MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
private void InitializeViewModel() {
    _vm = new MainViewModel(MainGrid);
    ...
    MyContainer.GetInstance().Container.RegisterInstance<MainViewModel>(_vm);
```

I can't get that [property injector] to work. Does property injection NEED to be paired up with a constructor? I am already using a constructor that has some parameters..

Comment: How are you creating the object that contains the Logger property?

Comment: That's what I suspected, see the answer from @WiktorZychia :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something's wrong in your example. If you want the `Logger` to be injected into `MainViewModel`, you'd have to let the container create the `MainViewModel` for you.

However, in your code you are creating it by yourself. As I look at it, it should be:

```
_vm = Container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
```

or at least

```
_vm = new MainViewModel();
Container.BuildUp( _vm );
```

Comment: thanks. that was it. Question, if i call Container.Resolve<MainViewModel>().. does that mean it will create a new instance of MainViewModel every time, or will it only instantiate it once, and return that instance on all subsequent calls to Resolve ?

Comment: `RegisterInstance` effectively implements a singleton behavior for your  object. It returns the same instance of `MainViewModel` for all subsequent calls to `Resolve`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: Andreas, thanks, RegisterIntance is self explanatory.. i was asking about Resolve behavior when NOT using RegisterInstance

Comment: ok just figured it out.. simply calling Resolve will always create a new instance.

Comment: @SonicSoul, that's `Resolve`'s default behavior. You can override that behavior by passing a `LifetimeManager` as a parameter to `RegisterType<>()`. See my full answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `new MainViewModel()` to create the viewmodel, you need to have your Unity Container do the creation.

```
Container.RegisterType<MainViewModel>(
     new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
     new InjectConstructor(MainGrid)
   );
```

And then you can use `Container.Resolve<MainViewModel>()` to get your singleton formerly known as `_vm`.

**Note:** The `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` part tells Unity to only create a single instance of MainViewModel and return it for everything.